# CSS for Reverse Indent?

Tags: css

Does anyone know if there's a CSS rule that causes a block of text to display a reverse indent - a block of text where every line is indented EXCEPT the first line, which aligns flush with the left margin?

I've discovered a few fixes which appear to be a little iffy - some use negative padding, some don't work in all browsers, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `margin-left` and a negative `text-indent`:

```css
.x {
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-indent: -30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="x">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p>
```